# Database: A design pattern for category features

Tags: mysql, database, design-patterns

I work for a system which has these tables:

`products` , `categories` , `features`

User wants to add some feature like `color` dynamically.

Which of this following ways are true?

**First one:**

```
Product             category                feature
----------------    ----------------        ----------------------------
pro_id (PK)         cat_id (PK)             feature_id (PK)
pro_name            cat_name                fea_name
cat_id (FK)         feature_id (FK)
```

We add a feature like `color`, then in category we choose that feature and add it to category table. Then we access for all product in that category.

But there is a pleonasm. Because when two category wants to have `color` feature, we must repeat `feature_id` column in category table.

**Second one:**

```
Product             category                name_feature
----------------    ----------------        ----------------------------
pro_id (PK)         cat_id (PK)             name_feature_id (PK)
pro_name            cat_name                cat_id (FK)
cat_id (FK)                                 color
                                            ...
```

When we enter a category, we create a table for that category. For example laptop category with `color` feature. We create a table called laptop_feature with features in **column**.

Which way is good? (Categories is limited)

Comment: Which is good depends on how you define 'good', but +1 for 'pleonasm'. Although (obviously) your first model has (presently) no place to store feature values (actually 'attribute' values) and your second model isn't dynamic.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks. But in second one if we have 100 category, we would have 100 feature table.

Comment: Yeah, that's not good, is it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new table

```
feature_category
--------------------
feature_id (FK)
cat_id (FK)
```

this will let you link common features to multiple categories.
- DO NOT make one table for each category :)

Comment: But your table is second one. Without making tables for each one, there shouldn't be cat_id here. We add all of features in one table,  and in `category` table we have a foreign key that tells us which feature belongs to that category.

Comment: correct, this is an additional table - it allows a MANY TO MANY relationship between categories and features - the way you are describing is a ONE TO MANY relationship, which does not seem to solve your problem.